# How to fix InstallShield Wizard Error -5011:0x8000ffff?

Tags: installshield

I encountered this error message while installing Hunting Unlimited 2010 software.

Error Screen:

[image: Error Screen]

The entire error message:

```
Error Code: -5011 : 0x8000ffff
Error Information:
>Kernel\ObjectWrapper.cpp (498)
>Kernel\IScriptWrapper.cpp (80)
>Kernel\ObjectWrapper.cpp (197)
>Kernel\IScriptWrapper.cpp (80)
>SetupNew\setup.cpp (478)
PAPP:Hunting Unlimited 2010
PVENDOR:Valusoft
PGUID:9ED06229-1F1B-4AE2-970D-5F731E8C8C35
$14.0.0.162PAK
@Windows Vista Service Pack 0 (9200)  Non IE/Netscape 1992.2
```

I tried running it as an administrator and running it in all compatibility modes. Nothing worked.

My Computer Features

- Acer Aspire E1-522
- AMD Radeon HD 8330 with 512 MB Graphics System Memory (4 GPUs) ~1.5GHz
- 8 GB DDR3 L Memory
- Windows 8 (64bit)
- DirectX 11

Write who knows how to solve this error.

Comment: check also on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/flexera-software-inc/installshield/error-5011_installshield-error-code-5011, it may be of help

The reason is mostly unknown. 
Please do your windows update before you try the options listed in the link.

Most of the times, it is related to VC++ runtime. Please try uninstall VC++ run time and install the latest